# Graphing in python using numpy

Tags: python, excel, csv, numpy, graph

I'm new at python so I'm probably missing something obvious

But I want to import data from excel and graph it. In excel there is one column with each row having a list of numbers separated by commas. I want to extract the second and third numbers from each array to use as x and y.

I've converted the excel file to a csv file.

```
fname = str("Raw1.csv") # store in data directory
data = np.loadtxt('../data/' + fname,
                delimiter=',',
                skiprows=6,
                usecols=(1,2,6,7,8,3,4,5)) 

x1 = data[:,[1]]
print x1
y1 = data[:,[2]]
print y1
```

But when i check that I've extracted the correct data, x1 shows the third number and y1 defaults to zero.

I'm not sure why this is happening?

Here's some example data from the csv file

```
"0, 57217.09, 51514.46, 58537.72, 44444.79, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.016, 
0.472, 0.170, 14:22:39.438"
"1, 56912.86, 51240.30, 58259.08, 44179.38, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.000, 
0.000, 0.000, 14:22:39.919"
"2, 58354.95, 52950.70, 59965.86, 45914.75, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.000, 
0.000, 0.000, 14:22:39.920"
```

Comment: could you provide the raw.csv or at least an example? seams you are not importing the right data. And that skip in the before delimiter is a typo??

Comment: Here's an example from Raw1.csv 
"0, 57217.09, 51514.46, 58537.72,......, 44444.79"
"1, 56912.86, 51240.30, 58259.08,........, 44179.38"

Comment: Hmmm where? Please edit your post and provide example data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.shape()` for finding the dimension of your data, then you can clearly see what's the actual mistake you are making and extract data from the list according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

From numpy docs

**usecols** : *Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example, usecols = (1,4,5) will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns. The default, None, results in all columns being read.*

So in your data, you have 2nd, 3rd, 7th and so on columns, `data[:,[1]]` is really the third number, `data[:,[2]]` is then 7th number (is it 0?)

Comment: Ah thank you. The first number is an integer, while the following are float numbers, so this error has come up:    ValueError: could not convert string to float: "0

Comment: The problem is not with converting integer into float with `np.loadtxt`. The error is in your usage of commas `"0` it tells python that the variable is string. You should have your .csv file without commas

Comment: Also note what `skiprows` is doing: *Skip the first skiprows lines; default: 0.*